# Send message to multiple emails using php mail

Tags: php

I have a table below in MYSQL

```
Mmeber_Email---------------Member_Name------Data---
mike01@yahoo.com  --------  Mike ---------- 100 ------
jacknick@gmail.com  --------Jack -----------50 ----
jillwag@hotmail.com  -------Jill ---------- 75 ------
jnash@gmail.com  --------   John ---------- 10 ------
```

Now, I have managed to extract the data from the database using PHP.
but i don't know how to email the data of each member on their respective email using PHP Mail function.
How should i tackle the problem of sending emails to multiple recipients using the PHP mail function below i.e Mike Should get the email containing the message 100, Jack 5 and so on..

```
<?php
$to = "somebody@example.com";
$subject = "My subject";
$txt = //data extracted from database using a common query comes here
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com";

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
?>
```

Comment: Loop through results?

Comment: you can just loop trough the data and set $to & $txt according to the data you have fetched and call mail() for each instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to loop through the results returned from MySQL. Here is an example:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) { // start loop

    $to       = $row['member_email']; 
    $subject  = 'the subject'; 
    $message  = "Dear ". $row['member_name'] . "\r\n";
    $message .= "Here is your data: " . $row['member_data'] . "\r\n";
    $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
       'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
       'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

The data from your database is contained in the `$row` array setup by the `while{}` loop.

Make sure to pay attention to the details for mail in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

Answer (score -1):

Set `$to` to a comma separated list of all the recipients:

```
$to = "somebody1@example.com, somebody2@example.com, somebody3@example.com";
```